# How add line spacing to a footnote with equations?

Tags: math-mode, line-spacing

I need to add some footnotes that explain the equations used to obtain certain results. However, one is a fraction with a floor function and extends to the upper and lower lines. 
How do I add space between the lines where equation of footnote 2 is touching equation of footnote 3 without affection the normal linespread of all other footnotes?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ceil{\lceil}{\rceil}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\floor{\lfloor}{\rfloor}

\begin{document}
    First equation\footnote{my footnote
                            $\mathrm{NMI}=(L+R)-P$}.
    Then second equation\footnote{Another footnote
                            $\mathrm{NMPI}=\floor*{\dfrac{(L+1)(R+1)}{P+1}-1}$}
    Then third equation \footnote{Long footnote longer explanation
                            $\mathrm{IL}=\dfrac{L \times R }{P}$}
    Final footnote with equation\footnote{This is the last footnote 
                                 but it has no equations.}
\end{document}
```

[image: footnote equation]

Comment: Why not use `$\mathrm{NMPI} = \floor*{(L + 1)(R + 1) / (P + 1) - 1}$`?

Comment: I fail to reproduce the output but if you replace  `$\mathrm{NMPI}=\floor*{\dfrac{(L+1)(R+1)}{P+1}-1}$` by `$\vphantom{\begin{array}{c}{}\\[1em]{}\end{array}}\mathrm{NMPI}=\floor*{\dfrac{(L+1)(R+1)}{P+1}-1}$` the spacing will increase. Of course, you can change `1em` to your liking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply add a `\vspace{1ex}` command inside the footnote.

```
Then second equation\footnote{Another footnote
$\mathrm{NMPI}=\floor*{\dfrac{(L+1)(R+1)}{P+1}-1}$\vspace{1ex}}
```

Comment: Thanks. Simple and working as I needed it.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `_{\mathstrut}` can add some depth to the expression not to interfere with the line below.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ceil{\lceil}{\rceil}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\floor{\lfloor}{\rfloor}

\begin{document}
    First equation\footnote{my footnote
                            $\mathrm{NMI}=(L+R)-P$}.
    Then second equation\footnote{Another footnote
                            $\mathrm{NMPI}=\floor*{\frac{(L+1)(R+1)}{P+1}-1}_{\mathstrut}$}
    Then third equation \footnote{Last footnote and longer explanation
                            $\mathrm{IL}=\frac{L \times R }{P}$}
    Final footnote with equation\footnote{This is the last footnote 
                                 but it has no equations.}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Another (and my own recommended) option is to use manually sized fine tuned delimiters instead of the too big `\left` and `\right`. Also, I don't think `\dfrac` is a good choice for a footnote.

```
$\mathrm{NMPI}=\bigl\lfloor\frac{(L+1)(R+1)}{P+1}-1\bigr\rfloor$
```

> [image]